# Getting "No data is available for the requested resource" on IE but no requests seem to fail

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have an app that is failing to load in IE. When I look in the console I see...

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0007, No data is available for the requested resource.
```

So it seems like there may be a problem with the charset or some other issue. I would like to know what I can do to figure out which request caused the issue. When I look at the POST requests they all seem to have a status of 200

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: @Jackie, did you ever figure this out? Similar issue here

Comment: Nope sorry guys